# Converting glm quaternion to rotation matrix and using it with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, quaternions, glm-math

so i have the orientation of my object stored in a glm::fquat and i want to use it to rotate my model. how do i do that?

i tried this:

```
glPushMatrix();
   glTranslatef(position.x, position.y, position.z);
   glMultMatrixf(glm::mat4_cast(orientation));
   glCallList(modelID);
glPopMatrix();
```

but i got this error:

```
error: cannot convert 'glm::detail::tmat4x4<float>' to 'const GLfloat* {aka const float*}' for argument '1' to 'void glMultMatrixf(const GLfloat*)'|
```

im obviously doing something wrong so whats the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLM won't/can't(?) automagically cast a `mat4` to `GLfloat*` so [you have to help it along a bit](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0265.html).

Try this:

```
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp> 
glMultMatrixf( glm::value_ptr( glm::mat4_cast(orientation) ) );
```

This might also work:

```
glMultMatrixf( &glm::mat4_cast(orientation)[0][0] );
```