# OpenGL Rotation with vertices not working

Tags: opengl, rotation, glm-math

I am trying to make a rotation with shaders on vertices, here is the code of my shader :

```
"#version 150 core\n"
"in vec2 position;"
"in vec3 color;"
"out vec3 Color;"
"uniform mat4 rotation;"
"void main() {"
"   Color = color;"
"   gl_Position = rotation*vec4(position, 0.0, 2.0);"
"}";
```

I am using it with a quat, here is the code producing the matrice and dumping it in the shader :

```
glm::quat rotation(x,0.0,0.0,0.5); 
x+=0.001;
ctm = glm::mat4_cast(rotation);
    GLint matrix_loc;

// get from shader pointer to global data
    matrix_loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "rotation");
    if (matrix_loc == -1)
        std::cout << "pointer for rotation of shader not found" << matrix_loc <<  std::endl;
// put local data in shader :
    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrix_loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ctm));
```

But when it rotates, the object gets bigger and bigger, I know i don't need to GetUniformLocation every time i iterate in my loop but this is the code for a test. GlUniformMatrix is supposed to make the rotation happen as far as I know. After these calls i simply draw my vertex array.

Comment: How does the `rotation` quaternion make it into `ctm`?

Comment: Huh, Ho god i think i just forgot to do the link, i was to focused on my code i did not notice it, i am going to give it a try tomorrow i will let you know.

Comment: it seems to be working but my object is rotating AND getting bigger, i have changed the quaternion to (x,0,0,1), thinking it would rotate around one axe but it is still getting bigger and rotating. Any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given its still drawing, `rotation` in the shader is probably a valid matrix. If it were an issue with the uniform it'd probably be all zeroes and nothing would draw.

As @genpfault says, ctm needs to be initialized:

```
ctm = glm::mat4_cast(rotation);
```

See: [Converting glm quaternion to rotation matrix and using it with opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032922/converting-glm-quaternion-to-rotation-matrix-and-using-it-with-opengl)

Also, shouldn't the `2.0` in `vec4(position, 0.0, 2.0)` be a `1.0`?

Comment: About the 1.0, it doesn't really matter much, does it ? it is just a question of how far will be the thing drawn from the reference right ? I think i changed it to 1.0 just to see how my programm would be affected, anyway it will probably be calculated later in the developement.

Comment: Ho you were right actually this parameter is used for clipping, by default is set to 1.0 but i wonder what it actually changes, i guess i will have my answer further in the developpement.

Comment: @user3714670 The most obvious change as you said will be scaling the translation of the matrix. It will affect the internal perspective divide too (`.xyz / .w`), but before then `gl_Position` expects un-normalized vertices for interpolation and culling. With regard to the scaling issue, I believe this is due to an un-normalized quaternion. The constructor isn't angle/axis. You want [`angleAxis`](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.0/api/a00184.html#a4412b01c376d9cfc9cc06b2d511d0f16).